# how to drop packets from specific source IP address on c#

Tags: c#, windows, network-programming, packet

i want to write an application for dropping some packets from some specific srcIP address.

i mean i want to write and run an application on a windows system that check all packet send requests from other applications that are run on that system and get srcIP address of that send requests and compare it with an IP address ; if the ip address was not XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX drop the packet before it send .

can anyone please help me to find the ways of doing it ?

is there anyone that have any c# source of it ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is essentially a firewall rule.

If manually setting such a rule from the Windows Firewall in Control Panel is not what you want, you can do it programmatically with [the API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366458(v=vs.85).aspx).  Everything you can do manually to the firewall from the Control Panel can be done from the API.

The other alternative would be to implement a [Winsock LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_Service_Provider). Looks like these APIs are deprecated (and for good reason)

Comment: yes you are right , but not exactly .. i want the block rule be enable if the request ip address was a specific one. and this is what can not be define on firewall rule . am i right ? (and i didn't know any thing about winsock LSP, can it cover this problem too ? )

Comment: You *can* do this with Firewall rules. You just have to get creative. Just create a rule that blocks everything to the remote server's port except in the SCOPE section of the firewall rule specify two ranges of IP addresses.  The first is every IP from 0.0.0.0 to a.b.c.[d-1] and another rule from a.b.c.[d+1] to 255.255.255.255.  I believe this will work for you.